# Is it possible to use MSBuild to build a .NET 1.1 VB project w/ Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, msbuild, crystal-reports, windows-vista, .net-1.1

I have a project with Crystal Reports files that doesn't seem to build correctly if I upgrade it to VS 2005 and .NET 2.0.  I think the reason is that the new version of Crystal Reports is incompatible with the older report format.  Since I am now running Vista, and .NET 2003 doesn't work correctly on Vista, I want to be able to build using MSBuild to target the .NET 1.1 framework.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 1.1 doesn't use MSBuild, but what you CAN do is convert the project to VS 2005, and use something called [MSBee](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=MSBee) to back-target your project to the 1.1 runtime.  I've never tried it, but that's probably your best bet.